# Android Constraint Layout doesn't stretch on full screen

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with layout which won't stretch within high resolution like 1920x1080.
As root layout I use Constraint Layout with following style:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context="njc.nhutrinhgold.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgNen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/xxhdpibg"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

and in Manifest.xml

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="960"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="960"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="960"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I want to stretch layout to any screen resolution but on emulator with high resolution it looks like this:

[image]

Actually I didn't figured out what is the problem

Comment: why you gave ConstraintLayout width and height static?

Comment: First, I used match_parent, but my Image auto stretch to small when I Choose match_parent in heigh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this, and tell me what are you getting, because this is the ideal way of doing this, since everybody is saying the same thing but do it like this. **match_parent** is generally the key

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
 tools:context="njc.nhutrinhgold.MainActivity">

<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imgNen"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:scaleType="centreCrop"
   android:visibility="visible"
   app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/xxhdpibg"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
   tools:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

**Remove adjustViewBound and set the scaleType as centreCrop, you'll see the change**

**NOTE : ** *This is for the layout to take up the whole screen and adjust (stretching to the whole screen)*

Comment: I set match_parent, but after run app, code auto adjust to Hardcode WxH..  android:layout_width="xxxdp"
        android:layout_height="xxxdp"

Comment: It is because the ration you've set doesnot let the image to expand properly. See by yourself **app:layout_constraintDimentionRatio** My code is for stretching the image to take up the screen.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgNen"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da

Comment: tried removing this line app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio=""

Comment: I run my code and image was lost http://www.upsieutoc.com/image/TJEwWG
http://www.upsieutoc.com/image/TJE0eE

Answer (score 1):

Don't hardcode the height and width of Constraint layout and the ImageView inside it. Set it to match_parent and it will stretch full screen in any device.

Comment: I set match_parent but it didn't

Comment: @alongquan In constraint layout instead of writing match_parent, you should do it from layout editor as it sets either height or width to 0dp which is must in Constraint layout to use match_parent.

Comment: Firstly, I set Layout and Image are MatchParrent but it not work, so I try to fix Width and Height but It still not work

Comment: Refer the link. It will help you understand. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: Now, when i Chose match_parent in menu option, it doesn't accept, system auto change to another number (223dp or 0 dp...)

Comment: Android studio automatically sets one of the properties of view to 0dp when used match_parent. But that's ok and no need to worry.

Comment: In the begining, It ok in Emulator, but not stretch on realdisplay.

Comment: Can you send me the screenshot of design part of your XML file?

Comment: I am not able to see the constraint layout part. Just send the design part so I can see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154653/discussion-between-alongquan-and-mehul-kanzariya).

Answer (score 0):

You have given hardcoded width and height. It will never stretch if you keep working on hardcoded width and height.